# which day of the week? - Ios Swift

Tags: ios, calendar, swift

i'm new in iOs and swift and i don't know how to give a day in format yyyy-mm-dd and a function response with the day of the week like:

2014-08-04 -> Monday ([0])

thanks

Comment: There are vast numbers of existing examples of using Cocoa and UIKit APIs to do this sort of thing in Objective C. I'd really recommend learning at least enough Objective C to be able to read them and translate them into Swift for yourself. It'll give you a big head start.

Comment: Sorry about this, but i dont have to many time for submit the app, i came from android and i read the swift book... but yep... i cant translate it from c++ or cocoa... i think everybody has his first time and it was a headache! thanks anyway, i will take ur advice for improve the app, but now we are rushing an mvp. Thx!!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

to take day of the week try this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
let dayOfWeekString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
println(dayOfWeekString)
```

Comment: And does exist the opposite way? week day from int?